# Apache repeatedly failing

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I am using xampp and apache to run php files on my pc. I have installed xampp multiple times and configured it so that apache is run on empty ports as is the most common online issue in forums I have consulted. Everything was running properly for a while and one day apache randomly failed again with the same error message : apache shutdown unexpectedly port blocked missing dependencies...etc. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it ran fine for a while. It is now repeating the error. Does anyone have experience or advice on this issue? (I am running windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tried is to disable Skype and switch ports Apache (as you've already seen hundreds of posts published) and that does not work, try running "setup_xampp.bat." If your installation has corrupted the BAT will leave this good.